# how to move data from sharepoint 2013 to foundation

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have trial version in SharePoint server 2013 and it expired , is it possible to move the data from SharePoint server 2013  to foundation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to migrate the SharePoint enterprise to SharePoint foundation. Because there are many features which are installed with Ent edition not available in SharePoint foundation. So backup & restore of site collection or backup & restore content db also will not work.

In this case, possible way is move the content using the 3rd party tools i.e sharegate or metalogix. as they offer free trail.